# What is difference between script: and before_script: inside a job in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

In `.gitlab-ci.yml` it is possible to add a default `before_script` that runs before all `script` in defined jobs.

My question is why define `before_script` in a job instead of just using the `script` in the job? Is using `before_script` inside a job is only to override the default `before_script`, or are there other circumstances or reasons for it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's mostly useful for jobs to add or override steps when using `include:` (templates) and/or `extends:` and/or globals/default for `before_script` as you mentioned.

For example, you may create a hidden key job that defines `script:` intended to be extended by other jobs. Those jobs which extend it can provide a `before_script:` key without overriding `script:` or vice versa.

```yaml
.install_dependencies:
  before_script:
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

my_test_job:
  extends: .install_dependencies
  script:
    - pytest
```

So, it's just for composition of jobs. Otherwise, there is no difference. `before_script:` and `script:` are simply concatenated together when the job runs.

It's worth mentioning also that `after_script:` *is* significantly different than `script:`/`before_script:`. `after_script` runs in a separate shell instance and will run under different circumstances. See [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script) for more info.

Comment: To reduce job duration. I want to run `install_dependencies` once!? B/w stages and jobs! Does `extends` help?

Comment: @Qamar that sounds like a separate question. As a hint: look into `cache:` and the [gitlab docs on caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-python-dependencies). If you still have questions after reviewing that, consider opening your own question.